# css background images doesn't show in Web developer in toolbar > Edit css

Tags: css, firefox, xhtml, web-developer-toolbar

I'm working on a xhtml css locally.

Why css background images doesn't show in Web developer toolbar > Edit css option?

Is there any workaround for it?

Has anyone faced this issue or I should reinstall firefox and plugin?

Comment: You mean "Edit CSS" is dropping values that are in the original CSS? I find that hard to believe. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use absolute paths in the image URLs. See this thread for more info:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=200043

Answer (score 0):

How about trying the [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) plugin? It has pretty great support for inspecting and debugging CSS.

Comment: in firebug we can't write css speedily like Web developer in toolbar > Edit css